# Left-flushing a set of equations while controlling the position of their numbers

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

For the following, I need to left-flush the equations to be adjacent to the left margin while controlling the position of their numbers so that, for example, the numbers need to be separated from the right margin by `0.3\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \begin{gather}
        \eta = 1-\exp\left(\dfrac{-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tau\right) \\
        \omega_j = \exp\left(\dfrac{-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tau_j\right)
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the class option `fleqn`, the equations will be flush left and you can use `newtagform` of `mathtools` to change the format of the numbers.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    \newtagform{Diaa}{(}{)\hspace{0.3\textwidth}}
    \usetagform{Diaa}
    \vspace*{\baselineskip}
    \begin{gather}
        \eta = 1-\exp\left(\dfrac{-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tau\right) \\
        \omega_j = \exp\left(\dfrac{-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tau_j\right)
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: @Mico: You're right. I have modified.

Comment: How can I switch from the tag form Diaa to the default?

Comment: @Diaa: Use `\usetagform{default}`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the option `fleqn` locally, you should use the package `nccmath` and its environment `fleqn`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\newtagform{Diaa}{(}{)\hspace{0.3\textwidth}}
\usetagform{Diaa}
\begin{fleqn}
\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\begin{gather}
\eta = 1-\exp\left(\dfrac{-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tau\right) \\
\omega_j = \exp\left(\dfrac{-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tau_j\right)
\end{gather}
\end{fleqn}

\vspace{1cm}
\usetagform{default}
\begin{gather}
\eta = 1-\exp\left(\dfrac{-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tau\right) \\
\omega_j = \exp\left(\dfrac{-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\tau_j\right)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion suits with one of my issues....